# Trying to update prices from an API using AJAX/Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

So I am trying to update prices on products, without having to refresh. I wat it to update live, but I don't understand. I have read a bunch of threads, but haven't figured it out.

Here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/bprices', methods=['GET'])
def bPrices():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[can get you a key if needed]').json()

    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["sell_summary"][:1],
            "buy_price": product["buy_summary"][:1],
            "sell_volume": product["quick_status"]["sellVolume"],
            "buy_volume": product["quick_status"]["buyVolume"],
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    return jsonify(products=products)
```

And here is my HTML + js:

```
<table
    id="myTable"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-dark sortable"
    cellspacing="0"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th aria-label="Product Name" data-balloon-pos="up">Product</th>
        <th aria-label="Product's buy price" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Buy Price
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Product's sell price" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Sell Price
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Product's buy volume" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Buy Volume
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Product's sell volume" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Sell Volume
        </th>
        <th>
          Margin
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="price"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root | tojson | safe }};
    (function () {
      $.getJSON(
        $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_stuff", // Your AJAX route here
        function (data) {
          $("#price").text(data.products)
        }
      );
      setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);
    })();
</script>
```

currently, it is only displaying a JSON file of the data I want to access, most likely because of the "jsonify".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the `JSON` data in a table view, loop through the products in jquery and create the table records inside a `tbody` element. Then insert this `tbody` into the desired table.

Here I have shown an example of displaying live data without page refresh using AJAX and Flask.

`app.py`:

```
from random import randint
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request



app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/get_data", methods=["GET"])
def get_data():
    products = [
        {
            "name": "mobile",
            "quantity": 3217210,
            "price": randint(1,1000)
        },
        {
            "name": "laptop",
            "quantity": 343217210,
            "price": randint(1,1000)
        },
        {
            "name": "mouse",
            "quantity": 100,
            "price": randint(1,1000)
        }        
    ]
    return jsonify(products=products)



@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    return render_template("products.html")
```

`products.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Live Prices</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Products</h3>
    <table border="1" id="products_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root | tojson | safe }};
        (function () {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/get_data",
            function(data) {
                var products = data.products;
                var table_body = document.createElement("tbody");
                $.each(products, function(index, product){
                    var product_name = product.name.toString();
                    var product_quantity = product.quantity;
                    var product_price = product.price;
                    var row = table_body.insertRow();
                    var name_cell = row.insertCell();
                    name_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_name));
                    var quantity_cell = row.insertCell();
                    quantity_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_quantity));
                    var price_cell = row.insertCell();
                    price_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_price));
                })
                $("#products_table tbody").remove();
                $("#products_table").append(table_body);
            }
            );
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: live data using flask and ajax]

Note: 
- In `get_data` route, I have generated random price between 1 to 1000 for each products in each `GET` request.
- In `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);` the `5000` indicates it will delay 5000 milliseconds(=5 seconds) between executions of the script.

Comment: no I dont really get it to work, I am still suck on the JSON page on my browser.

Comment: Have you tried running my give example? If you get successful to do so, you can implement it in your own code.

Comment: yeah, I tried yours. I think it has something to do with my jquery script. I had issues before when Jquery doesn't work, even though it's installed. I'm gonna try a few things.

Comment: hmm I tried installing jquery manually, and no luck at that part. I am just getting the JSON of products.

Comment: oh! found the issue. I didn't have a 'home' or a '/' route in my .py file. Let's just try to get my stuff in there haha, thanks for the help!

Comment: the "5000" at the bottom of js, that is how much it should wait after each update right?

Comment: When it says `[Object Object]`, what does that mean?

Comment: updated the answer with explanation on `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);`. `[Object object]` means array of objects. You can utilize console.log() to check the values in side the javascript.

Comment: I think it might be because `buy_price`&`sell_price` are float values?

Comment: `"sell_price": product["sell_summary"][:1],` it seems that you are storing a list in `sell_price`. Please debug the type of the value for which you are getting `Object object` in both Flask and JS. Flask debug:`print(type(object_name))`, JS debug: `console.log(typeof(object_name))`

Comment: I got back `<class 'dict'>` in flask, when doing it on JS I get `Object` in the console log.

Comment: After doing `print(type(products[1]))` & `console.log(typeof(product.sell_price))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215219/discussion-between-simon-sjoo-and-arsho).

Comment: I have done some research, tried to do `object.values(product_buyPrice)` but it doesn't work, how do I fix this? @arsho

Comment: @SimonSjöö, its being a long thread. Answering multiple questions is not appreciated in Stackoverflow. Please ask a separate question regarding only the jQuery portion. :)